# Do I need to call IsolatedStorageSettings.Save method in windows phone application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, application-settings

From the remarks section of [IsolatedStorageSettings.Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) page:

> Data written to the IsolatedStorageSettings object is saved when the
>   application that uses the class is closed. This can occur when the
>   user closes the Web browser, refreshes a page, or browses away from
>   the page. If you want your application to write to isolated storage
>   immediately, you can call the Save method in application code.

So, I can never call the `Save` method and every setting will be in safety. I'm just curious in what usecases should I use the `Save` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to call `IsolatedStorageSettings.Save` yourself. As mentioned in the 'Tips and Warnings' section at the bottom of the [class reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you have to save it yourself in order to make sure it's written to the file.

> The IsolatedStorageSettings class is not automatically saved
>   to disk when values are written. Saves are done in a finalizer, which is
>   usually but not always run when the application shuts down. To ensure saves are
>   actually performed we need to call the Save method after each write or set of
>   writes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for the IsolatedStorageSettings.Save method dated February 14, 2014:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save(v=vs.105).aspx

And an excerpt the from it (see the Caution):

> However you don’t have to call the Save method on Windows Phone. The
>   data that you store in the IsolatedStorageSettings object is saved
>   automatically.

My dev experience also proves that - the settings are saved automatically without the need to call the Save method explicitly. But note that it happens only when you close the whole app, excatly as it is stated in MSDN:

> Data written to the IsolatedStorageSettings object is saved when the
>   application that uses the class is closed. If you want your
>   application to write to isolated storage immediately, you can call the
>   Save method in application code.